# OrientDB - Create Automatic Index with Java

Tags: java, orientdb

When creating an index through sql in orientDB, I can set it to automatic by doing:

```
create index MyClass.my_field on MyClass (my_field) unique
```

As I add records to the DB, my index gets updated.  However, if I create the index with Java by doing the following:

```
OClass target = db.getMetadata().getSchema().getOrCreateClass("MyClass");
target.createProperty("my_field", OType.STRING);
target.createIndex("MyClass.my_field", OClass.INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE, "my_field");
db.getMetadata().getSchema().save();
```

My index is successfully created, but doesn't update automatically.  Is there some flag I can set to the index creation to tell it to update as I save new records?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not a great solution, but I ended up doing:

```
String sql = "create index MyClass.my_field on MyClass (my_field) unique"
OCommandSQL createIndex = new OCommandSQL(sql);
Object done = db.command(createIndex).execute(new Object[0]);
```

and it works.  I'm never a fan of writing raw sql in my code though...

Answer (score 0):

The code above works for me on orientdb 1.7.9, i.e. the index created natively is indeed automatically updated, just as one would expect.

Comment: how can I check if the index is being automatically updated from my code?